# Is there a work around for Operator ‘+’ cannot be applied to types 'string | number' and 'string’ | number'

Tags: typescript

Background is I’m calling a function within a function that can either return a string or a number, and want to add that to another value. But am running into that error.

I’ve tried doing a check

```
function addNumbers(obj):number | string {
 const returnedValue = helperFunction(obj.blah) //this could be a number or string
 if (Number.isNaN(returnedValue) === false) {
  return returnedValue + anotherValue;
 }
 return ‘-’;
```

I assumed the Number.isNaN would get rid of the error but it didn’t. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wX2G1m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  There should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Number.isNaN` checks specifically for the value `NaN`. `NaN` is a special number that's returned by computations like `0/0`. Most numbers and all strings will cause `Number.isNaN` to return `false`, and so the type is not narrowed down to exclude strings.

Instead, I recommend you do this:

```
if (typeof returnedValue === 'number') {
  return returnedValue + anotherValue;
}
```

Comment: Great explanation this worked perfectly thanks

Answer (score 1):

wrap the type with ()
eg: `(number | string)`

however it'll still fail as you return null at the end as well

so your return type should be `(number | string | null)`